# VBA solver looping

Tags: vba, loops, solver

I am trying to get solver to repeat on multiple rows of data. Here is my code so far. I am new at this and this does it for 2 lines. I would like it to run until the last row. I added in the range line after reading the responses from similar questions.

```
Sub prgopt()
'
' prgopt Macro
'

'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$C$2", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$A$3:$B$3", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:=" GRG Nonlinear "
    SolverSolve
    Range("$C$2").Offset(Count, 0).Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$C$3", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$A$3:$B$3", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:=" GRG Nonlinear "
    SolverSolve
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your time and thanks for the help
C

Comment: it depends on how you want to loop, will it be for a certain number of times or until something is true?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just need it to run the solver and optimize on each row until there are no more. Each row is a separate group of data.

Comment: @doctor, Thank you for your code suggestion. I have run that program and did not get the desired results. The goal is to minimize the sum or squared residuals on a series of data sets by changing two factors in an equation. each row is a separate set of data with its own equation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub prgopt()

'
' prgopt Macro
'

'

    Dim c As Range
    dim nRows as int
    nRows = 2
    For Each c In Range("$C$2:$C$3")
        SolverOk SetCell:=c.Address, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=c.Offset(0, -nRows).Resize(1, nRows), _
            Engine:=1, EngineDesc:=" GRG Nonlinear "
        SolverSolve userfinish:=True
        SolverFinish keepfinal:=1
    Next

    End Sub
```

Change the range and nRows (width of the factor range) as needed. Hope this helps.